# Showing a function is well-defined $g\left( \frac{p}{q} \right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am attempting to show a function is well-defined. It clearly is, but showing it is true in general is difficult. First, let's look at a function which is not well defined.

Let $f\left( \frac{m}{n} \right)=\frac{m+1}{n+1}$. Consider $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$.

$$f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)=\frac{2}{3}\neq \frac{3}{5}=f\left( \frac{2}{4}\right)$$

Now, let $g\left( \frac{m}{n} \right)=\frac{2m}{3n}$. Given a fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ and any equivalent representatin $\frac{x}{y}$. We have

$$g\left( \frac{p}{q} \right)=\frac{2p}{3q}=\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\frac{2x}{3y}=g\left( \frac{x}{y} \right)$$

Is this a proper demonstration? i.e. it doesn't work for

$$f\left( \frac{p}{q} \right)=\frac{p+1}{q+1}$$

where we can't say anything else since there is no way to make a replacement for $\frac{x}{y}$?

Comment: You've mixed up your twos and threes but overlooking that, what you have done is sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. This is a proof that the function is well defined.